# Can I alter a formula that links to another workbook where the worksheet that is being referenced is obtained from the value of a cell

Tags: excel, function

This is a relatively simple question. I have a formula, let's say it's ='C:@Work\Things\Small Things[Ants.xlsx]Fire Ants'!Q$1484. In the worksheet I'm using which uses this formula to obtain a value I have a cell P6 which is the name of the worksheet. This worksheet which contains this formula I just showed is called blue ants. The cell P6 changes when I change the name of the worksheet.(This formula does this =REPLACE(CELL("filename",A1),1,FIND("]",CELL("filename",A1)),"")).

Now my question is if it's possible for the Worksheet(Fire Ants) in the 1st formula showed to actually reference Cell P6. For instance the Formula would look somewhat like ='C:@Work\Things\Small Things[Ants.xlsx]P6 '!Q$1484. Atleast this is the idea of the formula I hope to have. I want to do this because I have multiple Sheets in the ants File. I would like to quickly pull information on different sheets by just changing the name of the worksheet i'm using which then changes cell P6. This should be a relatively easy solution, (I hope atleast) but I just can't figure this out.

BTW I just made up the workbook as an example of what i'm trying to do.

Comment: I think you want [`INDIRECT()`](https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-indirect-function). See [here](https://exceljet.net/formula/indirect-named-range-different-sheet) too.

Comment: I should've specified that the workbooks that are being referenced are going to be closed so as far as I'm aware the indirect function will not work then. Is there another method to dynamically change worksheet references from another workbook when the workbook is closed.